# Preview display of editor on SO shows embedded underscore in name turning italics on but actual display doesn't

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-preview, underscore

This is an old chestnut - but it is silly that the preview display is not in synch with the main display and I ran across it again.  The mismatch makes it hard to be confident that what you are seeing is what you will get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's open source -- feel free to contribute a patch!

http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/

Comment: That assumes I can write JavaScript.  I believe it has a C in the name, so it must be like C code - should be easy!

Comment: Wait, but where is the code? Isn't it at GitHub right now? There isn't any code in the SVN of wmd-new @ googlecode or in the downloads... what do you mean, Jeff?